# Service invoked too many times: translate. What is the quota?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am receiving this error message "Service invoked too many times: translate" in my google apps script. My script is running every 5 minutes. How could I find what is the quota ?
Is there a way to increase this limit ?
I have not had this problem in the last days. It just appeared today.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) Dashboard. Select your project, then click on "APIs" in the left-hand menu. On that screen, click on the "Enabled APIs" tab.

If you don't have never used Google Developers Console, then step one would be to sign up. Then, create a new project, enable the Translate API, use the API keys provided during the setup in your project. Now you can track your usage.

However, I believe the Google Translate API is a Paid-for-only API. That could be your core problem?

Comment: I have enabled the API through the Console how you suggested. I don't see how you make the link between the API and the actual script itself (maybe I did not understand what you said regarding the API Keys).  Then you are right, it seems to be a paid API but I am wondering then why it worked until now.

Comment: Google Translate API has nothing to do with the App Script's LanguageApp (if that's what the question author is using).